# Unknown Script running in the head of my website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nginx, malware

My website is running on Wordpress on a Nginx/Ubuntu server. 
Recently I tried to make some ads on Google but it prompted me with a policy violation on Malicious or unwanted software. 
I got in contact the the Google team and they gave me some links that appear on my webpages. These are:

> https://staleshow.com/v2/0/fovR3B4fjiQSgtNFpGy....
>
> https://staleshow.com/v2/0/gemRIkJ9djEBOXuetqaLkIOcy.....
>
> https://staleshow.com/v2kzbtsxmzq-clIED28ZJ-mROoqs5UKBLIXem7WuN....
>
> https://staleshow.com/v2vgtikD8J6e0uNhC1Rgy5NIHONmkM-LSTIbr_enq_ckOqCgI....

When inspecting my website with dev tools I can see that a script is running in the head tag. Follows:

```
<script>!(function(o,n,t){t=o.createElement(n),o=o.getElementsByTagName(n)[0],t.async=1,t.src="https://staleshow.com/v2/0/fovR3B4fjiQSgtNFpGy....",o.parentNode.insertBefore(t,o)})(document,"script"),(function(o,n){o[n]=o[n]||function(){(o[n].q=o[n].q||[]).push(arguments)}})(window,"admiral");!(function(n,e,r,t){function o(){if((function o(t){try{return(t=localStorage.getItem("v4ac1eiZr0"))&&0<t.split(",")[4]}catch(n){}return!1})()){var t=n[e].pubads();typeof t.setTargeting===r&&t.setTargeting("admiral-engaged","true")}}(t=n[e]=n[e]||{}).cmd=t.cmd||[],typeof t.pubads===r?o():typeof t.cmd.unshift===r?t.cmd.unshift(o):t.cmd.push(o)})(window,"googletag","function");</script>
```

How can I delete this line? Where is it's origin?

Comment: I think google SEO related code

Answer (score 0):

Have you visited staleshow.com? It says

> About this domain This domain is used by digital publishers to control
>   access to copyrighted content in accordance with the Digital
>   Millennium Copyright Act and understand how visitors are accessing
>   their copyrighted content.

I'm guessing it might be a copyright tracker recognized as malware by Google?